# sed delete lines not matching patterns in txt file

Tags: shell, sed, regular-expression, macos

I'm dealing with a txt file that lists a bunch of other txt files, a lot of which I have wrongfully duplicated.

I'm on macOS so the lines listing the duplicated files all end with the pattern `(NUMBER).txt`. I want to delete all the lines that don't contain this pattern.

I came up with this command to test the regex but it does not work as it also prints the lines that end with `(WORD).txt`:

```
sed '/\(\d\)\.txt$|\(\d\d\)\.txt$|\(\d\d\d\)\.txt$/p' file.txt
```

I know I'm missing something but I can't figure out what... Thanks for your help!

Comment: See [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y) - it will answer several issues like which metacharacters should be escaped, `\d` not supported, etc

Comment: `\d` is not (traditional) `sed` regex syntax; instead it's just a `d`; did you try to read the sed manual page?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
sed -E -n '/.*[0-9]+\.txt$/p' file.txt
```

If you take a look at [info sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html), at the paragraph 2.1 you will find some examples of how to use the combination `sed -n '...p'`.

The above command prints to stdout. If you want to modify the file in place add the `-i` option.